# Setting proxy through bash script in ubuntu

Tags: bash, networking, ubuntu, proxy, system

I am using the gsettings tool to set up system proxy automatically[System Settings-> Network proxy], SO i made a simple bash script with these lines:

```
 gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'auto'
 //for another mode
 gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode 'none'
```

I place this script in /etc/network/if-up.d because I want the script to run when my laptop connects to the internet. I saved a copy of the script in my home folder and when i run the copy, the script seems to work fine and i can see the changes in network proxy window however when i run the script in /etc/network/if-up.d folder, the settings don't seem to be applied for some reason. What am i missing here?

Comment: Hi, did you make your script work?

Comment: No @emil , I tried your solution, but its not working :/

Comment: Did you try my latest comment on my answer, to run sudo -s etc manually? Do you get any error message? Otherwise you could print all environment variables using `env` and try to set some/all until you succeed. Last alternative could be to use `strace gsettings args` and compare the output.

Comment: Hey @emil, Thanks a lot for your continued support! I tried this command strace gsettings args and when i run the bash script stored in  /etc/network/if-up.d/ i get a system trace error: gsettings command not found. I think it could not locate the specific file /usr/bin/gsettings for some reason, but when i save the bash script in my home folder, i can see a list of commands executed and that the /usr/bin/gsettings file is correctly identified and loaded. What do you think might be the cause of this?

Comment: Sounds strange that the location would matter, do the scripts have the same contents also are they executed the same way? I think it would be helpful if you update your question with the current contents of your script and also how you are executing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made the script work! Its been a week since i got stuck with the  **gsettings tool**. Now, what I wanted to accomplish was to run the gsettings tool to set the proxy for a user although the bash script that did thas was owned by root and thus only had the root environment variables. Now this can be generalised for any command, to run a commad as a specific user, we can just do:

```
su username -c "command to execute"
#replace username by your username in the bash script
```

If the command contains only a single word, the double quotes could be removed. I am so happy. I do not need to switch profiles and manually set the proxy configurations[ip addresses etc], everytime I connect to the internet.

Hope this helps somebody with a similar problem :D

Comment: Are you sure you mean `sudo` and not `su`? The following syntax can be found in the manuals `sudo(8)` or `su(1)`: `sudo -u username command` or `su username -c command`.

Comment: oh I am really sorry @emil, it should be 'su' I just checked the script. I will edit the answer right away. Thanks for pointing it out!